# sqlite3_step taking forever on IOS 8.2

Tags: sqlite, ios8.2

### I am running the below select query, it was working 100% before iOS 8.2. This query was returned perfect result set in iOS 8.1 and older. The App is stucked on sqlite3_step, it taks forever to complete. Any one with a idea why? My App is stuck on the users devices. Below is the query and the code.

```
NSString *sqlStatement = @"Select W.woorde, R.woorde, W.woordIDs, R.woordIDs from masterWoorde W, masterWoorde R, masterWaardes WD, masterWoorde Rr where Rr.woorde LIKE ? And Rr.woordIDs=WD.skoonLeidraadID and WD.leidraadID=W.woordIDs and WD.resultaatID=R.woordIDs ORDER BY W.woorde COLLATE NOCASE, R.woorde COLLATE NOCASE";
```

---

```
if (prepareStatus == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(select_statement, 1, [dboObject.frases UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);

            while (sqlite3_step(select_statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                productSModel * aProduct = [[productSModel alloc] init];
                aProduct.frases = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 0)];
                aProduct.ABC = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 1)];
                aProduct.CDE = sqlite3_column_int(select_statement, 2);
                aProduct.FGH = sqlite3_column_int(select_statement, 3);

                [arrResult addObject:aProduct];
            }
        }
```

Comment: `sqlite3_step()` is what actually executes the query. Show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for this query with the SQLite versions of iOS 8.1 and 8.2.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been traced to changes in SQLite between iOS 8.1 and iOS 8.2. See [Sqlite3 query gets really slow under iOS 8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033730/sqlite3-query-gets-really-slow-under-ios-8-2)